# gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin terminates

Tags: ros, gazebo, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while launching current shadow robot hand in Gazebo,
there is an error:
[ INFO] [1427997617.853023607, 0.752000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception

Gazebo simulator freezes.
If I launch other robots, there is not error with gazebo_ros_controller_manager.

Is it because of the empty namespace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206527/gazebo_ros_controller_manager-plugin-terminates/) by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-04-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-04-02**:
Sounds like a bug in the controllers for the shadow robot hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosclean purge

---

Originally posted by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) with karma: 53 on 2015-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0